# Prototip-like plug-in for jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins, user-interface

I am very impressed with the [Prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/) plug-in, and I was wondering if there we're a similar plug-in available for jQuery?

The plug-in has to have been around longer than a few months and has to be updated regularly--or at the very least; on new releases of jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one resembles pretty well on aspect and features:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Comment: the problem with qTip is that the 1.0.0-rc3 does not work with jQuery 1.4.2 and 2.0.0pre is still too buggy, so there's actually no stable release

Answer (score 2):

this plugin [jquery-tooltip plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) is around since end 2006
i have used it before, though it does not offer that many options as your prototip, it does have customization, and viewport repositioning, events blocking, styling, ...

tough i have no idea about the timeframe between updates.

Comment: Not as many options and doesn't look as cool as the Prototip plug-in, but I guess I'll just put our designer to work and append some generated markup :) Thanks, Sander.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Tipped for jQuery by Nick himself

http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped

Comment: Funny that this wasn't mentioned earlier since it's by the same developer!